# Conditional statements based on custom meta value in category archives

Tags: categories, archives, conditional-content, footer

Here's what I need to do. Insert a short Javascript in the footer using wp_footer. No problem there for single posts, I have this.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'prefix_wpfooter' );
function prefix_wpfooter() {
    global $post;

    if( is_singular() ) {
        $hide_page = ( empty( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_prefix_hide_page', true ) ) ) ? '' : get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_prefix_hide_page', true ) ;
    }

    if( $hide_page == '1' ) {
        ?>
        <!-- Output JS here -->
        <script>
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```

However, this won't fly for front_page or category archives. I'm having a brain fart and thought I'd seen a solution to this before. Can anybody help start me in the right direction or point me to a solution because I don't think I'm using the right search terms and coming up empty.

Many, many thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "won't fly"? The JS isn't loading or is there some other problem?

Comment: The only circumstance where the code in your second `if` would execute is when the value associated with the `_prefix_hide_page` key is `1`. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: The JS won't load at all in archive pages and front pages. e.g looking at my code, the `<script></script>` doesn't appear at all. It also doesn't appear if I remove the `is_singular` condition on these archive pages.

@s_ha_dum yes. I need it to **only** execute if the meta value for _prefix_hide_page = 1

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, I ended up doing something like this which I am certain isn't the best way. Seems like a lot of work just to get to the nugget. Could've sworn I've seen a simpler way but it's escaped me all day. This is ugly and probably highly inefficient but it works. Please do let me know or point me to a better solution if you know one.

```
global $posts, $post;
if( is_front_page() || is_archive() ) {     
$hide_pages = array();
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $hide_pages[] = ( empty( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_prefix_hide_page', true ) ) ) ? '0' : get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_prefix_hide_page', true ) ;          
        }
        if( in_array('1', $hide_pages, true) ) {
            $hide_page = '1';
        }
    }
```